# URL not redirecting in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a new website wherein I have installed codeigniter (latest). 
Now for testing I have a form in my default page www.example.com . I have removed the index.php from the url with the help of .htaccess . Now if I submit the form , I have redirected it to www.example.com/controller_name/function_name . The URL shows perfect as I have written

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>controller_name/function_name" method="post" >
```

Plus I have my base_url as http://www.example.com .

Now the problem is, after redirecting to www.example.com/controller_name/function_name it throws a no page found error. But I have written `echo "test";` in that function .

Could anyone help me out in figuring the issue.

Comment: have you defined the route in `config/routes.php` ?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?  Also the .htaccess you are using

Comment: Does it shows a codeigniter generated 404 page, or the one from the webserver?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like either your htaccess is set up wrong or you need to change your $config['uri_protocol'].  can really tell without any code...

Comment: @peacemaker - this is the htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: @complex857 - it shows the one from the webserver

Comment: @orourkek - what routes are you talking about ? 

this is the ones that is mentioned in my routes.php

$route['default_controller'] = "cuff";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my setup - which also modified htaccess to remove index.php - I had to set my config file to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and I am using Request URI:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Before changing these things I was also getting a page not found.  Try this and see if that works for you.

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is that you are not calling the controller correctly.  what is the name of the controller? are you using the correct spelling/case?  It would be helpful if you posted the actual code instead of "controller_name/function_name"

Answer (score 0):

the problem is how you have been removing the index.php

I sure that if you try to post to `<?php echo base_url(); ? >index.php/controller_name/function_name` , it will work.

you have to redit you .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

This is how my setup looks like:

**config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1/ [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That's correct, but I think that set correct **base_url** is better if you want to use CodeIgniter URL Helper; it can be set as  'http ://www.your-site.com/' or 'http: //localhost/' for local web server. **uri_protocol** in most of case working fine as 'AUTO', it need to be changed only for certain web hosting php configuration.

Comment: I prefer the autodetect because it simplifies deploy from scm, or other automatic means. I guess not everyone needs that. The url helper and other libraries uses the autodetected value without problems in my experience, like `site_url()` works as expected.

Comment: @complex857 - it still doesnt work , Throws a server's page not found error .

Comment: Could be that your webserver doesn't read .htaccess files, if you are on apache, check if the `mod_rewrite` is enabled and the `AccessFileName` and `AllowOverride` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a new CodeIgniter installation can be a problem for who do it for the first time, but I can assure you that is more easy than you can think.

Maybe a tutorial that I have done for CodeIgniter workink on eleven2 provider can help you:
[www.eleven2.com/forum/topic/247-codeigniter-framework/](http://www.eleven2.com/forum/topic/247-codeigniter-framework/)

Please check if you setup CodeIgniter correctly as described on tutorial; if it's all ok, we must find problem in php configuration or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controller_name/function_name" method="post" >
```

or simply u can use:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(controller_name/function_name); ?>" method="post" >
```

Damn sure it will works

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, using CI 3.1.5. Fixed it with this setting.

**config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';    
$config['base_url'] = '-your domain-';    
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Put .htaccess file outside "application" folder

Comment: Answers like this are only really helpful if you can explain _why_ your fix actually resolves the issue.